# codeigniter temporary session to give user edit option

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to give users the option to add a title to content they've just added for 5 minutes after they post. Am I doing this correctly?

In `config.php` I've set `$config['sess_expiration']` to `300` (5mins)
and when they add the content I set the session in my controller:

```
$values = array(
    'image_id' => $uploaded_image_id,
    'session_id' => $this->session->userdata('session_id')
);

$this->session->set_userdata('edit', $values);
```

And in my view im currently checking for the session like this:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit')) : ?> 
<?php
$session_info = $this->session->userdata('edit');
if ($session_info['image_id'] == $alpha_id 
    &&
    $this->session->userdata('ip_address') == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
    &&
    $session_info['session_id'] == $this->session->set_userdata('session_id')) :
?>
```

Within that `if()`, an edit title form is then shown

FYI, `$alpha_id` is the contents `id` from the URI.

Is how I'm going about this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `set_userdata` when you're really trying to read the session data.

You could also assign within the if clause:

```
<?php if ( $session_info = $this->session->userdata('edit') ): 

    if ($session_info['image_id'] == $alpha_id 
        &&
        $this->session->userdata('ip_address') == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
        &&
        $session_info['session_id'] == $this->session->userdata('session_id')
    ):
        // Do stuff
    endif;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for spotting that, fixed it. Also how can I make it possible to edit 2 things at once? Currently now if I post something and then something else quickly the first edit permission gets overwritten, meaning only the 2nd post can be edited. I'd like unlimited sessions to be possible, how do I do this?